# SQLException when using a PreparedStatement for Derby DB

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have an SQL query that i am going to run using a PreparedStatement, and it is

```
UPDATE tbl_HitsCounter SET count = ? WHERE keyid = (SELECT id FROM tbl_HitsMaster WHERE sitename = '?')
```

Now when i set the 2nd paramater, which is a string value, i am getting a strange SQLException.

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 99);
preparedStatement.setString(2, masterKey);
```

As the setString() method is executed, i am getting an SQLException

```
The column position '2' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '1'.
```

I have no idea what this is about, i havent even executed the executeUpdate() method.

Comment: shouldn't that be keyid IN (since you aren't doing a SELECT DISTINCT in the subquery?_

Comment: tbl_HitsMaster has it as id only

Comment: yes, sitename will appear once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one placeholder in your SQL but you are trying to assign a value for the second. Your problem is that you have quoted the second placeholder, your SQL should look more like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_HitsCounter
SET count = ?
WHERE keyid = (
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl_HitsMaster
    WHERE sitename = ?
)
```

Note the lack of quotes in `sitename = ?`. This is a placeholder: `?`. This is an SQL question mark string literal: `'?'`.